# Problem with using RuleDelayed (:>)

Tags: rule, coefficients

I have defined a rule using rule delayed function as follows:

```
innerWithDxU = (f1_ D[f2_[x,y],x]f3_[x,y]  :>-f2 [x,y]D[f1 f3[x,y],x] );
```

```
a[x,y] = 1;
c = Coefficient[a[x,y]D[U1[x,y],x]U2[x,y] /.innerWithDxU,U1[x,y]]
```

What I expect this code to do is if I give 1*Dx(U1[x,y])*U2[x,y] , the answer I expect is -Dx(U2[x,y]) (which would be the coefficient of U1[x,y])

Now the problem I am having is, if I pick a[x,y] = 1, the output c I'm getting is 0. Which is incorrect. But If I use anything other than a[x,y]=1 (e.g: 1.0, U[x,y], 0.9 etc), for every other case it works.

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: Perhaps change the `f1_` to `f1_.` (no space between the underscore and the period). Your expression doesn't match because `a[x,y]` is set to 1, and so there is no extra quantity `f1` to match multiplying the other functions. `f1_.` is a pattern that will match if there's any expression there or nothing.

Comment: Thanks it solved the problem.